# Encountering endless loop with error: Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, model-view-controller, devise

I have two model vendor and customer, in the application controller I defined  `after_sign_in_path_for` method for each model, but after sign up and confirm for customer, when I log in, I redirected to vendor log in page instead of `dashboard_path`. Is this problem occur because I put both model's methods in the application controller, should I have put each method in their appropriate sessions controller?

I believe the cause the the wrong redirection is an endless loop. Is there any wrong with the application controller code below?
I have only written in this application controller, everything else is devise built in.

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
    # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    before_action :authenticate!

    def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
        if user && user.is_a?(Customer)
            customer_dashboard_path
        elsif user && user.is_a?(Vendor)
            vendor_dashboard_path
        end
    end

    def after_sign_out_path_for(user)
        if user && user.is_a?(Customer)
            root_path
        elsif user && user.is_a?(Vendor)
            root_path
        end
    end

    def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(user)
        if user && user.is_a?(Customer)
            root_path
        elsif user && user.is_a?(Vendor)
            root_path
        end
    end

  def authenticate!
      if @current_user == current_customer
          :authenticate_customer!
          elsif @current_user == current_vendor
          :authenticate_vendor!
      end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are have same method written twice(method override) with different params. So it will always pick the second method `after_sign_in_path_for(vendor)`. You can change the method names to what you are expecting for example and call methods accordingly.

```
 def after_sign_in_path_for_customer(customer)
   dashboard_path
 end

 def after_sign_in_path_for_vendor(vendor)
   dashboard_path
 end
```

Or else  you can have a common method like following

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
  if user && user.is_a?(Vendor)
     redirect to vendor dashbord
  elsif user && user.is_a?(Customer)
     redirect to customer dash board
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried to follow the second example, but it didn't change the behavior of the website, I forgot to mention that I'm using devise, these methods are provided by devise

Comment: what is the relation ship between the models ? customer and vendor? are they. I guess since you have before actions for both authenticate_vendor! and authenticate_customer! . one of them returns false and it redirects to login page as it thinks you are not signed in.

Comment: There is no relationship between 2 models, both serve 2 different purposes

Comment: ok, so you have two before filters authenticate_customer! and authenticate_vendor! . when logged in as customer would these two returns true or will it returns false for authenticate_vendor! hence the redirection

Comment: yeah may be that is the cause of the problem, can i define a new method with iff statement that check for which type of user to authenticate?

Comment: yes I think so, you can have a single before filter to authenticate both type of users. if else can be used based on what other data you gets from login form.hope that helps

Comment: weird now i get undefine customer local variable in those methods, but this variable worked before

Comment: if I am seeing correctly it needs to be if user && user.is_a?(Customer) user.is_a?(Vendor)

Comment: i changed to that actually, and now when  click on sign up or log in button i would take me directly to the dashboard instead of log in form

Comment: have you tried logging out and accessing it again. if it results the same after loggin out .. your new authenticate! method is returning true even you are not logged in..trying debugging that method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111577/discussion-between-khoavo-and-shani).